# OpenCL convert uint4 to unsigned int

Tags: type-conversion, opencl

How do I convert uint4 type to unsigned int ? I am reading an image in the kernel using readimageui(). This returns uint4 type.

In the host code I tried using a buffer of type cl_uint4 when reading back results into the destination buffer but that didn't work out.

Comment: What is the format (channel order, data type) of your image? It probably suffices to just take the `.x` component of the returned `uint4` value.

Comment: As above  there's not enough context on what's required.  The question should elaborated to give a bigger picture of the overall problem.    Be careful of the effect from what you ask for.  The highest order bit in the unsigned int if set  gives the largest component to the image channel intensity. When that is converted to signed Int the high order bit  could get dropped or become a negative sign bit!  If be better  to shift the int and lose thw low order bit.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the structure of `uint4`. It probably looks like how @reima said.